# REST API: Create Deployment throwing error BadRequest

Tags: rest, azure

We are trying to access the Create Deployment method stated below
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460813
We have uploaded the Package in the blob and browsing the configuration file. We have checked trying to upload manually the package and config file in Azure portal and its working fine.
Below is the code we have written for creating deployment where "AzureEcoystemCloudService" is our cloud service name where we want to deploy our package.

```
    byte[] bytes = new byte[fupldConfig.PostedFile.ContentLength + 1];
        fupldConfig.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        string a = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        string base64ConfigurationFile = a.ToBase64();
        X509Certificate2 certificate = CertificateUtility.GetStoreCertificate  
        (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["thumbprint"].ToString());


        HostedService.CreateNewDeployment(certificate, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings   
        ["SubscriptionId"].ToString(), "2012-03-01", "AzureEcoystemCloudService", 
        Infosys.AzureEcosystem.Entities.Enums.DeploymentSlot.staging,
        "AzureEcoystemDeployment", "http://shubhendustorage.blob.core.windows.net/shubhendu
        storage/Infosys.AzureEcoystem.Web.cspkg", "AzureEcoystemDeployment", 
        base64ConfigurationFile, true, false);   



    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="certificate"></param>
    /// <param name="subscriptionId"></param>
    /// <param name="version"></param>
    /// <param name="serviceName"></param>
    /// <param name="deploymentSlot"></param>
    /// <param name="name"></param>
    /// <param name="packageUrl"></param>
    /// <param name="label"></param>
    /// <param name="base64Configuration"></param>
    /// <param name="startDeployment"></param>
    /// <param name="treatWarningsAsError"></param>
    public static void CreateNewDeployment(X509Certificate2 certificate, string 
    subscriptionId,string version, string serviceName, 
   Infosys.AzureEcosystem.Entities.Enums.DeploymentSlot deploymentSlot, string name, 
   string packageUrl, string label, string base64Configuration,
        bool startDeployment, bool treatWarningsAsError)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(String.Format(Constants.CreateDeploymentUrlTemplate, 
        subscriptionId, serviceName, deploymentSlot.ToString()));
        XNamespace wa = Constants.xmlNamespace;
        XDocument requestBody = new XDocument();

        String base64ConfigurationFile = base64Configuration; 
        String base64Label = label.ToBase64();
        XElement xName = new XElement(wa + "Name", name); 
        XElement xPackageUrl = new XElement(wa + "PackageUrl", packageUrl);
        XElement xLabel = new XElement(wa + "Label", base64Label);
        XElement xConfiguration = new XElement(wa + "Configuration", 
        base64ConfigurationFile);
        XElement xStartDeployment = new XElement(wa + "StartDeployment", 
        startDeployment.ToString().ToLower());
        XElement xTreatWarningsAsError = new XElement(wa + "TreatWarningsAsError", 
        treatWarningsAsError.ToString().ToLower()); 
        XElement createDeployment = new XElement(wa + "CreateDeployment"); 

        createDeployment.Add(xName); 
        createDeployment.Add(xPackageUrl);
        createDeployment.Add(xLabel); 
        createDeployment.Add(xConfiguration); 
        createDeployment.Add(xStartDeployment); 
        createDeployment.Add(xTreatWarningsAsError);
        requestBody.Add(createDeployment);
        requestBody.Declaration = new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "no"); 
        XDocument responseBody;
        RestApiUtility.InvokeRequest(
            uri, Infosys.AzureEcosystem.Entities.Enums.RequestMethod.POST.ToString(), 
        HttpStatusCode.Accepted, requestBody, certificate, version, out responseBody);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// A helper function to invoke a Service Management REST API operation.
    /// Throws an ApplicationException on unexpected status code results.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="uri">The URI of the operation to invoke using a web request.</param>
    /// <param name="method">The method of the web request, GET, PUT, POST, or 
    DELETE.</param>
    /// <param name="expectedCode">The expected status code.</param>
    /// <param name="requestBody">The XML body to send with the web request. Use null to   
    send no request body.</param>
    /// <param name="responseBody">The XML body returned by the request, if any.</param>
    /// <returns>The requestId returned by the operation.</returns>
    public static string InvokeRequest(
        Uri uri,
        string method,
        HttpStatusCode expectedCode,
        XDocument requestBody,
        X509Certificate2 certificate,
        string version,
        out XDocument responseBody)
    {
        responseBody = null;
        string requestId = String.Empty;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = method;
        request.Headers.Add("x-ms-Version", version);
        request.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
        request.ContentType = "application/xml";
        if (requestBody != null)
        {
            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(
                    requestStream, System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    requestBody.Save(streamWriter, SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
                }
            }
        }
        HttpWebResponse response;
        HttpStatusCode statusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unused;
        try
        {
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            // GetResponse throws a WebException for 4XX and 5XX status codes
            response = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
        }
        try
        {
            statusCode = response.StatusCode;
            if (response.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    responseBody = XDocument.Load(reader);
                }
            }
            if (response.Headers != null)
            {
                requestId = response.Headers["x-ms-request-id"];
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            response.Close();
        }
        if (!statusCode.Equals(expectedCode))
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(string.Format(
                "Call to {0} returned an error:{1}Status Code: {2} ({3}):{1}{4}",
                uri.ToString(),
                Environment.NewLine,
                (int)statusCode,
                statusCode,
                responseBody.ToString(SaveOptions.OmitDuplicateNamespaces)));
        }
        return requestId;
    }




  But every time we are getting the below error from the line

  response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    <Error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <Code>BadRequest</Code>
      <Message>The specified configuration settings for Settings are invalid. Verify that the service configuration file is a valid XML file, and that role instance counts are specified as positive integers.</Message>

</Error>
```

Thanks,
Shubhendu

Comment: See also http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/08ea3289-0f10-4bc5-8f39-6124a1afd22c/

Answer (score 4):

I've had problems with request on the azure rest API. I find reading response of the WebException to be invaluable.

```
try
{
    //Call Azure REST API
}
catch(WebException ex)
{
    var err = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

    Console.WriteLine(err);

    throw;
}
```

This should give you sufficient information about the underlying problem with the request.

Answer (score 0):

As of Azure SDK 2.2, it ends up the documentation here is wrong and you don't need to base64 encode the configuration string.  So instead of doing all the byte[] conversion to base64, just pass in an UFT8 string.